# meizu mx4 no boot no recovery

Tags: ubuntu-touch, data-recovery, meizu-mx4

I was playing with the terminal.

- `sudo apt-get update`, no problem
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`, no problem

But when it finished with the upgrade the phone stopped working.
Didn't open any apps so I did a reboot.
But it won't start anymore, it stays at the meizu logo.
When I try to go to recovery I get the Ubuntu logo and nothing works.

Comment: Since when ubuntu can be installed on a meizu mx4 phone?

Comment: Meizu mx4 Ubuntu edition

Comment: Alright, didn't know that actually existed.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it back to work.
With my Ubuntu laptop and the right commands I was able to flash Ubuntu touch.
I didn't even lost my data.

ubuntu-device-flash touch --device arale --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/meizu.en